# Navigation Bar Back Button, text not center alligined

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios5, uinavigationbar

I am customizing the back button in the navigation bar using appearance proxy, also setting image and text attributes. Everything works fine but the text in back button is not center aligned.

Here is my code.

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:title style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
 UIImage *buttonBack32 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationBackButton"] 
                         resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 5)];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonBack32 forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
 [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        [UIColor whiteColor], 
        UITextAttributeTextColor, 
        [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8], 
        UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
        [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)], 
        UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
  [UIFont fontWithName:@"xxx" size:16.0], 
  UITextAttributeFont,
  nil] 
                                            forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

If I set the font size "0.0" then text becomes too small in size and still not centered aligned.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you referring to vertical alignment or horizontal alignment?

Comment: i think try this may help not sur but i do this thing in textview and also lable but not in BarButton so i will just try and then post the answer [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter]; :)

Comment: ParasJoshi:it does not worked.

Comment: m talking about vertical alignment

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the setTitlePositionAdjustment:forBarMetrics: method to set the title offset as required. For example:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 5.0f) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Worked for me (y)

Answer (score 2):

To adjust the text up I had to use this:

```
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -1.5) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score -4):

```
You can use this :

UIView* leftContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 4.0, 70.0, 44.0)];
UIImage *profileImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"account-btn.png"];
UIButton *profilebutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
profilebutton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 7.0, 70.0, 30.0 );
[profilebutton setImage:profileImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[profilebutton addTarget:self action:@selector(profileBtnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[leftContainer addSubview:profilebutton];

UIBarButtonItem* item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftContainer];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;

[leftContainer release];
[item release];
```